# How to add a user manually to SugarCRM database?

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

I want to make a registration form which will add user to the SugarCRM database directly. I have tried to add user data to four tables to accomplish this which are:

1. users
2. acl_roles
3. email_addresses
4. email_addr_bean_rel

I was able to add user successfully but when I try to login with the newly created user I get this error:

> You have been logged out because your session has expired.

Whereas the user is exist in MySQL database but it is not being shown in SugarCRM "User Management" panel table.

Comment: Why the database directly? Could you use web services i.e. the Rest API?

Comment: How to get started with rest api for sugarcrm ?

Comment: By reading this: [SugarCRM Developer Guide 6.5 Web Services](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/02_Application_Framework/Web_Services/)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are not generating proper access token for the user , You need to generate a token which will get access into the sugar then  you can do the tasks using that access token.So you have to use rest API.

[Check this link it will help you to use Rest API](https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2014/02/28/sugarcrm-cookbook1/)

Answer (score -3):

The issue will solve by the following method

> In users table all the tinyInt field should be the value 0 or 1